# Error in Accessing External Sqlite Database on android app on mobile

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, genymotion

I am new to android development. I am using genymotion as emulator and android studio as development platform. I am also using external sqlite database file for my app.

It is working fine when I am running on emulator but it is forced stop when i am trying to run on my mobile.(my database size is 20 MB).

Comment: can you post some of the logcat errors / exceptions?

Comment: Did you upload the db to your phone?

Comment: No my phone is not rooted.if i am generating .apk then also db uploading to phone is required?